# How can I free memory and at the same time return a pointer?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, free

I have these functions

```
char *hash(char *stringa, char *tipohash) {
    if (strcmp(tipohash, "md5") == 0) {
        stringa = md5(stringa);
    }
    return stringa;
}

char *md5(char *stringa) {
    unsigned char risultato[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    int i;
    char *hashfinale = malloc(sizeof(char) * MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2);
    MD5((const unsigned char *)stringa, strlen(stringa), risultato);
    for (i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf(hashfinale + 2 * i, "%02x", risultato[i]);
    }
    return (char *)hashfinale;
}
```

How I can return `(char *)hashfinale` doing the free without losing the value of the string?

This is the caller

```
char *hashlinea = hash(stringa, hashType);
```

Comment: Document the function as returning a pointer that needs to be passed to `free`, and let the called handle it.

Comment: Or you could modify the signature to get the a pointer to the first character of an array (plus the length of the array) and use that, without any dynamic allocation by your function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't understand what you said

Comment: The question is, if you free the pointer in the function, it's no longer usable, so returning it invokes undefined behavior, you should return the pointer, like you do, and free it wherever you call the function after you use the returned pointer.

Comment: You should `malloc` one more byte to fit the terminating 0 byte.

Comment: @anastaciu The problem is that if i free it from the caller it fills the memory, so I think i have to free it in the called

Comment: @helloworld, if don't you have enough memory there is little you can do, you aleady have only one instance of the object, there are no copies involved, I don't see how you could use less memory. Check SomeProgrammerDude's solution, it may help.

Comment: @anastaciu I have 16 gb of memory, the problem is in the code, not in the HW

Comment: @helloworld, in that case, I don't see a problem, use one of the solutions presented, pass the array(or allocated block) as a parameter, or return the pointer and free it in the caller, these are the two ways you can do it.

Comment: You don't free memory if it's still in use.  When you're done using it, *then* you free it.

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is. Do you want to return a pointer to a string or not? If yes, you need to return a non-freed pointer. If not, why do you return a pointer/value?

Comment: Also the cast of the returned pointer from `md5` seems pretty redundant as it is already a pointer to `char`. What is its purpose?

Comment: @helloworld: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two ways to solve the problem, and none of them involves your code calling `free`.

---

The first way is to just do nothing different from now, except to add documentation so the user of your `hash` function knows that the code must call `free` on the returned pointer:

```
// This is the code using your function
char *hashlinea = hash(stringa,hashType);

// Some code using hashlinea

free(hashlinea);
```

---

The second way is to pass a pointer to an existing array, and your code use that array instead of allocating it using `malloc`:

```
char hashlinea[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
hash(stringa, hashType, hashlinea);
```

For this your `hash` function needs to pass on the third argument to the `md5` function, which should use it instead of allocating memory:

```
char *md5(char *stringa, char *hashfinale){
    unsigned char risultato[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    int i;
    // No memory allocation here
    MD5((const unsigned char *)stringa, strlen(stringa), risultato);
    for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf(hashfinale + 2*i,"%02x",risultato[i]);
    }
    return hashfinale;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. IMO it is better to pass the pointer to the buffer. The caller will be responsible for the memory management

```
char *md5(char *stringa, char *hashfinale){
 ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that if a free it from the caller it fills the memory, so I think i have to free it in the called

Comment: @helloworld Your whole idea seems incomplete. I hint back to the comment section of your question. This approach is the best one if you think more about what you want to do.

Comment: Although this answer is a little rare with information, I give an upvote as it shows the *presumably* correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `md5` function: the size allocated for the MD5 hash must be one byte longer for the null terminator:

```
char *hashfinale = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2 + 1));
```

Note that in C  (and C++) `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, so you could just write:

```
char *hashfinale = malloc(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2 + 1);
```

Regarding your question, `hash` returns either its argument or an allocated object. This is a problem for memory management, as yo may not know later in the program if the return value must be freed or not. Passing the destination array for the hash string is a better alternative, otherwise you should duplicate the string so the return value of `hash` can be unconditionally freed:

```c
char *md5(const char *stringa) {
    unsigned char risultato[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    int i;
    char *hashfinale = malloc(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2 + 1);
    MD5((const unsigned char *)stringa, strlen(stringa), risultato);
    for (i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf(hashfinale + 2 * i, "%02x", risultato[i]);
    }
    return hashfinale;
}

// always free the return value
char *hash(const char *stringa, const char *tipohash) {
    if (!strcmp(tipohash, "md5")) {
        return md5(stringa);
    } else {
        return strdup(stringa);
    }
}
```